# What is the alternative to `TiXmlNode::FirstChild(const char *)` in TinyXML-2?

Tags: c++, tinyxml, tinyxml2

I am updating code that uses the [legacy TinyXml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/annotated.html) library, to use [new TinyXML-2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2docs/index.html) version instead.

While editing, I noticed that the function [`TiXmlNode::FirstChild(const char *)`](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlNode.html#1f05828d023150706eeb16d6fb3f6355) has no direct replacement in [TinyXML-2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2docs/classtinyxml2_1_1_x_m_l_node.html).

My questions are:

1. Is there a convenient replacement for the aforementioned function that I missed?
2. In case there isn't, how should the example code below be updated for TinyXML-2?

```cpp
// TiXmlElement *element; // assume this was correctly loaded
TiXmlNode *node;

if ((node = element->FirstChild("example")) != nullptr)
{
    for (TiXmlElement *walk = node->FirstChildElement();
        walk != nullptr;
        walk = walk->NextSiblingElement())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tinyxml2 has

`const XMLElement * XMLNode::FirstChildElement (const char *value=0) const`

Your code block is much the same:

```
if (auto example = element -> FirstChildElement ("example")
{
   for (auto walk = example -> FirstChildElement();
        walk;
        walk -> NextSiblingElement())
   {
   // walk the walk
   }
}
```

Or you might look at [my add-on for tinyxml2](https://github.com/stanthomas/tinyxml2-ex) with which your snippet would be:

```
for (auto walk : selection (element, "example/")
{
   // walk the walk
}
```